# In-class constructor initialisation of a vector in C++

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I have class `MyClass` as below. I would like to initilaise the attributes of `MyClass` through a constructor. The arguments `b_` and `c_` should have the defaults `{"abc", "_"}` and `0` respectively.

```
class MyClass {

    size_t a_;
    std::vector<string> b_;
    size_t c_;

public:

    MyClass(
            size_t a,
            optional<std::vector<string>> b = {"abc", "_"},
            size_t c = 0)
        :   a_(a),
            b_(b),
            c_(c)
        {}
}
```

This gives me the error: `error: could not convert ‘{"abc", "_"}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘isf::optional<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >’`.

I then tried:

```
class MyClass {

    size_t a_;
    std::vector<string> b_;
    size_t c_;

public:
    const std::vector<string> VEC = {"abc", "_"};

    MyClass(
            size_t a,
            optional<std::vector<string>> b = VEC,
            size_t c = 0)
        :   a_(a),
            b_(b),
            c_(c)
        {}
}
```

This gave me the error: `error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘MyClass::VEC’`.

Making `VEC` static also did not solve the issue: `error: in-class initialization of static data member ‘const std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > MyClass::b’ of non-literal type`

What would be the correct way of declaring a default value for the vector of strings in the constructor?

Comment: what is `isf::optional` ? Please post a [mcve]

Comment: why are you using an optional when anyhow it either gets a parameter passed or not but then it has a default, it is always a vector, never not a vector

Comment: `isf` is the namespace

Answer (score 2):

The right way is to use a `std::vector<std::string>>`:

```
MyClass(
            size_t a,
            std::vector<std::string> b = {"abc", "_"},
            size_t c = 0)
        :   a_(a),
            b_(b),
            c_(c)
        {}
```

There is no use of `optional` here, because either the caller does pass a vector or the caller does not pass a vector but then the default is used. As you want to initialize the member always, passing `nullopt` is not an option either. Hence, just drop the `optional`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved in the following way:

```
class MyClass {

    size_t a_;
    std::vector<string> b_;
    size_t c_;

public:
    const std::vector<string> DEFAULT_VEC = {"abc", "_"};

    MyClass(
            size_t a,
            optional<std::vector<string>> b,
            size_t c = 0)
        :   a_(a),
            b_(b.value_or(DEFAULT_VEC)),
            c_(c)
        {}
}
```